# terraform plan error : unsupported argument : An argument named "point_in_time_recovery_enabled" is not expected here

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'am trying to create a google cloud sql instance via terraform and i have to enable point in time recovery option but I have the following error :

Error: Unsupported argument

on cloud-sql.tf line 39, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "si_geny_postgres_logfaces":
39: point_in_time_recovery_enabled = true

An argument named "point_in_time_recovery_enabled" is not expected here.

**here is my terraform file** :

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "si_geny_postgres_logfaces" {

  project          = google_project.current_project.project_id
  region           = var.region
  name             = "si-sql-instance"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_12"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy  = true
    ignore_changes = [
      settings[0].disk_size, name
    ]
  }

  settings {

    tier = "db-custom-2-7680"
    availability_type = "REGIONAL"

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      private_network = data.google_compute_network.si_shared_vpc.self_link
    }

    location_preference {
      zone = var.gce_zone
    }

    #disk
    disk_type       = "PD_SSD"
    disk_autoresize = true
    disk_size       = 10 #GB

    backup_configuration {
      binary_log_enabled = false
      point_in_time_recovery_enabled = true
      enabled    = true
      start_time = "00:00"    // backup at midnight (GMT)
      location   = var.region // Custom Location for backups => BACKUP REGION
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day = 1
      hour = 3
      update_track = "stable"

    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">0.12.18"
}

provider "google" {
  version = "=3.20.0"
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  zone = var.gce_zone
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "=3.20.0"
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  zone = var.gce_zone
}
```

Any idea please?

Comment: I'd imagine you need to update your terraform provider to the latest version. Typically these errors are because this property was introduced later than the provider your using

Comment: Looks like the latest version is [3.40.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: that said I can see nothing in the release notes about this property so it might be a bug

Comment: thanks @Liam you are right it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically when you get these:

> An argument named "..." is not expected here.

issues on terraform. First thing to check is that your file is correct and the property in the error is actually listed in the docs ([which this one is](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html)).

Next thing is to check that your using the latest version of the provider. As properties are introduced they get added to the documentation but it's not always obvious which version of the provider they were added. You can check to see whichever is the latest provider from the [release notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

So you should upgrade your provider version to the latest (3.40.0) as of time of writing:

```
provider "google" {
  version = "=3.40.0"
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  zone = var.gce_zone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want to use availability_type to create a multi-region high-availability instance, the following error occurs:

```
    │ Error: Unsupported argument
│   on main.tf line 35, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "mysql613ha":
│   35:   availability_type = "REGIONAL"
│ An argument named "availability_type" is not expected here.
```

Terraform version:

```
Terraform v1.4.6
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.67.0
```

main.tf:

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "yzh-test-358106"
  region      = "asia-southeast1"
}

#https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "mysql613" {
  name             = "my613tftest"
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"
  region           = "asia-southeast1"
  availability_type = "REGIONAL"
#https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs

  settings {
    # Second-generation instance tiers are based on the machine
    # type. See argument reference below.
    tier = "db-custom-2-6144"
    disk_size = 100

    backup_configuration{
      enabled = true
      binary_log_enabled = true
      location = "us"
    }
   
  }
}
```

Have you ever encountered this problem?